# R times out when accessing POSTGRESQL db

Tags: r, postgresql

I'm using the POSTGRESQL package to access a database and R times out and crashes every time when connecting ("The previous R session was terminated due to an unexpected crash"). Terminal says *'abrt-cli status' timed out*.

I've tried accessing the same db through SSH and it works. Our sysadmin thinks the credentials are correct, and says R seems to be working fine for him (although he's doing completely different work that has nothing to do with accessing postgresql databases). I've tried naming the server rather than using 'localhost', just in case, and that doesn't work either. But even if the credentials were wrong, I feel like I'd get an error rather than a crash.

I realize this might have to do with our local configuration, but I'm at the end of my rope. I'd be extremely grateful for any ideas people have.

```
# Install the package RPostgres

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(DBI)
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(tidycensus)

# The user needs to input their password

input_password <- rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password")


db <- [CENSORED, I PROMISE IT'S CORRECT :)] 

host_db <- 'localhost'  
db_port <- '5432'  
db_user <- 'leviem'  
db_password <- input_password

drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")

conn <- dbConnect(drv, 
                 dbname = db,
                 host = host_db, 
                 port = db_port,
                 user = db_user, 
                 password = db_password)

# List all the tables available
dbListTables(conn)

# Close the connection
dbDisconnect (conn)
```

Comment: "I've tried accessing the same db through SSH and it works"  What does that mean?  If you are connecting to localhost, why would you have to ssh to yourself before doing so?  Or did you use ssh to set up a tunnel?  Please show what you did.

Comment: What OS, and flavor, and version?  What version of R?  How did you install it?  Are you running R directly on a command line or through some kind of wrapper?

Comment: Thank you, and apologies for the incomplete question. R and POSTGRESQL are both running on the same remote server operated by my employer, hence “localhost,” although I also tried the name of the server. 

I access R studio remotely through a browser, and I can also access the db by opening an SSH connection to the remote server and starting psql.

Comment: I believe we're running R 4.1.2 on a Linux server, but the server is down for maintenance so I can't check right now for sure.

Comment: I think this is a problem with how the browser, R-studio and R interact.  That is, it is either causing the problem, or is producing a mangled error message which doesn't reflect the real cause of the problem.  Can you check the db log file to see what it thinks the problem is (or if indeed it it thinks there is any problem)?  Or maybe R has some server-side log file with better messages you can check.

Comment: That’s fair. I’ll look into if there are better logs and repost here.